# How to handle errors in a cross thread operation

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, error-handling, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control created at runtime and used via a background thread. The following is an example of the code used:

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then Me.Invoke(Sub() webbroswers(3).Document.GetElementById("ID").InnerText = TextBox4.Text)
```

This works great! But sometime the webbrowser doesn't have the element "ID" (for example). So I'd like a method to basically allow the code to continue if an error occurs. I've tried the try - catch block but this doesn't catch it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a multi-line lambda expression, like this:

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then Me.Invoke(
    Sub()
        Dim element As HtmlElement = webbroswers(3).Document.GetElementById("ID")
        If element IsNot Nothing Then
            element.InnerText = TextBox4.Text
        End If
    End Sub
    )
```

Checking if it's `Nothing`, like that, is more efficient than letting it fail and catching the exception.  However, if you need to do a Try/Catch for any other reason, you can also do that easily in a multi-line lambda expression, for instance:

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then Me.Invoke(
    Sub()
        Try
            webbroswers(3).Document.GetElementById("ID").InnerText = TextBox4.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' ...
        End Try
    End Sub
    )
```

However, if the lambda expression gets too long, or if you'd like to have more meaningful stack traces in your exceptions, you can use a delegate to an actual method, like this:

```
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then Me.Invoke(AddressOf UpdateId)

'...

Private Sub UpdateId()
    Try
        webbroswers(3).Document.GetElementById("ID").InnerText = TextBox4.Text
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' ...
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer. Very complete. Thanks!